# How to allow and secure endpoints in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
            //cia apsirasau tuos endpointus kuriuos leidziu neprisijungus:
    .antMatchers("/admin/login", "/admin/register","/teams").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHabdler)
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtauthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

This is mys configure method, the problem is that I want lets say allow to access /teams endpoint for everyone, but when I start my program and go to /teams endpoint it asks for authentification. Where is the problem?

Comment: 'refect'? reject?

Comment: What url are you calling... You only allowed acces to `/teams` so if you have a url with `/teams/<some-id>` it will not match and ask for a login.

Comment: /teams is a list of teams. And I want to access it without authorization.

Comment: @GabrielėAgnėNormali Show your `JwtauthenticationFilter` class. Show also the headers of your request. What does *but when I start my program and go to /teams endpoint it asks for authentification* mean? Do you see browsers authentication dialog?